# Server error when I try to upload a file to Sharepoint 2016

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise

I'm getting this error when I try to upload a file:

[image]

I know this can happen for many reasons and I've tried fixes suggested online.  My local drive has enough space, Sharepoint Central Administration v4 is running in IIS and I've tried different file types and sizes.  Nothing that I've tried works.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Does it happen on all browsers?

Comment: Not sure.  I'm only using IE 11

Comment: You mentioned you have tried online suggestions. What all have you tried? Have you checked in all documents in that library? Changed name and tried again?

Comment: I checked my local drive has enough space, Sharepoint Central Administration v4 is running in IIS and I've tried different file names, types and sizes.

Comment: Can you create a new test library and upload that file. This is to make sure if the issue is across all libraries or just with one specific library.

Answer (score 1):

Run `Install-SPApplicationContent` and try again.